# AngularJS - Render multiple strings and HTML files in a single tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, ng-bind-html

I want to render template files (view + controller) and multiple html strings both together in a single tag.
- So I have some strings like

```
<p>some text</p>
```

and html files + controller like

```
template.html + template.controller.js
```

I want to render the strings and the template.html into one tag.

I already connected the html strings and I'm able to render these with

```
<div ng-bind-html="template" ..></div>
```

Can I serialize the html files and render it in ng-bind-html too? These files have own controllers:

```
<div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
```

They would lose functionality?

NOTE: The order of the elements is important!!! For example, I want to render the string, then the content of the file and then again a string.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not use ngInclude?

Comment: Because I want to add strings like "<p>test</p>" too, and ng-include is only for urls.

Comment: Not sure but I think what you want are directives combining controllers and templates... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Am I able to include multiple files with a single ngInclude?

Comment: @MaxBerg no but you could ng-repeat ng-nclude iterating over the Urls.

Comment: @Wawy: nice idea!! But what about the strings?

Comment: @MaxBerg Why do you need to serialise a html to a string? what's wrong with ngInclude?

Answer (score 2):

You should use directives. This will allow you to load a html file with an associated js file. You can set scope.someText in the directive and call it in the view e.g.

```
 <p>{{someText}}</p>
```

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.directive('someTextDirective', function(){
    return{
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'path/to/html/file.html',
         link:function(scope){
              scope.someText = 'blah';
         }
    }
});
```

Simply call the directive in your html:

```
<some-text-directive></some-text-directive>
```

Hope this helps. If I have not been clear let me know and I will do my best to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Is this also possible with multiple template urls? For example, If i wanna join two strings with two templates?

Comment: oke, maybe i can combine the strings and templates in the template of the directive. In the template of the directive I can ng-repeat over ng-include and also render the strings.

Comment: Possibly. Instead of templateUrl you could also use template. Template simply takes html code instead of pointing to a file e.g. template: '<p>{{someText}}</p>'