# How to render multiple html files one after the other angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, optimization

I have many html templates that need to be rendered to a single page. Is there any way to render each individual template one after the other so the user doesn't have to wait for all of them before navigating the page?

Each section is templated out and i'm using directives to access them in a main html file. Each template also accesses a database so i think that's what's slowing down the rendering process. I guess what i'm asking is whether there is a way in angular to access the data and render for the first few templates and let the user navigate the page, while the rest are in the process of rendering.

```
<company-header ctrl='infoCtrl' class='company-fixed-header'></company-header>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class='dynamic-container'> 

        <div class='content'>
            <section id='details'>
                <company-Identifiers-List ctrl='infoCtrl'></company-Identifiers-List>
                <contact-Information-List ctrl='infoCtrl'></contact-Information-List>
                <company-Information-List ctrl='infoCtrl'></company-Information-List>
                <regulatory-Filing-List ctrl='infoCtrl'></regulatory-Filing-List>
                <securities-Manuals ctrl='infoCtrl'></securities-Manuals>
            </section>
            <section id="securities">
                <security-info ctrl='infoCtrl'></security-info>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to be a lot more specific, question is pretty vague ...but yes, there are numerous ways to render multiple html files....angular is designed to do just that

Comment: Agreed with @charlietfl, need more information. If loading is an issue, you may want to consider injecting your templates inline into the main index.html file.

Comment: why not to use nested directive....

Comment: You can follow this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895509/angularjs-render-multiple-strings-and-html-files-in-a-single-tag)! Hope this will help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a different way to fix your problem, which is loading your partials in the $templateCache (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache). This way you don't have to make an AJAX request for each view when they're needed, therefore loading the content of your directives virtually immediately.

You could do something like:

```
$templateCache.put('company-identifiers-list.html', '<div>your content</div>');
$templateCache.put('company-information-list.html', '<div>your content</div>');
```

Additionally, if you're using Grunt, you could automate this task using [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates).